# how to resolve data validation fail in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, validation

Ive created the following mongodb collection

```
db.createCollection("task3",
                   {"validator": {"$and": [ {"Company.cname":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.city":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.street":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.bldg#":{"$type":"int"},
                                 "Company.bldg#":{"$gt":0},
                                 "Company.bldg#":{"$lt":500},
                                 "Company.budget":{"$type": "double"},
                                 "Company.budget":{"$gt":0},
                                 "Company.Department.floor":{"$type":"int"},
                                 "Company.Department.dname":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.first_name":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.last_name":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.enumber":{"$type":"int"},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.date_of_birth":{"$type":"date"},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.position":{"$type":"string"},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.position":{"position":{"$exists":false},
                                 "Company.Department.Employee.salary":{"$type":"double"}}]}});
```

im attempting to insert the following data

```
db.task3.insert(

        {  "Company":{ 
                "cname":"Google",
                "city":"Sydney",
                "street":"Pitt Street",
                "bldg#":NumberInt(100),
                "budget": 100000.0,

                "Department":{
               "dname":"Google",
               "floor":NumberInt(4),

         "Employee": {"first_name" : "George",
         "last_name": "Martin",  
        "enumber" : NumberInt(109),
         "date_of_birth": new Date('Dec 26,1981'),  
         "salary" : 70000.0 }}}});
```

When attempting to do so i recieve the following error

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

I understand the meaning behind the error but i am unsure as to why i am recieving it because my insert seems to follow all the contraints ive set, but clearly something is wrong. Thankyou

Comment: In your validator, `Department` is a field of Company, but not in the json you insert.

Comment: @L.Sanna what would the correct json look like then ?

Comment: @L.Sanna Ive updated my insert with how i believe you'd do the Json insert properly but it still gives the same error